# FireBase OrderBy timestamp then look for the highest number of responses [Android]

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to Look for posts that are between two different timestamps then grab them by the highest number of yes responses. I have tried filtering as much as I can on the server side then doing the rest on the client side but this will not work if I have a large data set. I have also tried combining strings together for example.

1482434266~0010

Timestamp followed by the number of yes responses but, when ordering by this method the timestamp takes precedence over the number of yes responses.I understand that firebase does not allow multiple where clauses and have tried to come up with alternate solutions to this problem but have not reached a suitable solution.

[This is how my Post Structure look like](http://prntscr.com/dpfdcj)

has anyone encounter this issue before and have solved it? or am I doing something completely wrong here ?

Comment: You will have to order by StartAt&EndAt like you did, and the second order is gonna be in the app side.

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Can you leave an example of input/output of what you're expecting?

Comment: https://codedump.io/share/tGhSOCNDOUAr/1/json-files

Comment: I am expecting to receive everything within a specific time frame, for example, everything from 7 days ago sorted in order from the highest number of yes responses (1482434366~0070,1482434466~0040,1482434266~0035,1482434466~0030,1482434766~0020,1482434266~0010,1482434666~0005,1482434166~0002)